# Change values of custom option of product in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I added two `custom options` for the product in `magento 1.9`. The `custom Options` are:

> 1. Title: Shape
>
>    sku: shape
>
>    input type: drop-down
>
>    values: Rectangle, Round, Oval
> 2. Title: Color
>
>    sku: color
>
>    input type: drop-down
>
>    values: Red, Blue, Green, White, Black

And these displayed in product page successfully. My problem is

> When user select `Rectangle` from `shape` drop down the second drop
>   down, `colors` should only load `Red, Blue, Green` only.

That is depending upon the values in `shape` drop down I have to change the values in `color` drop down for the product.

How can I do this? Please help me..I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**

Comment: Create a module with a controller you can call. On document load, add handlers to the change event of the Shape custom option drop down. The handler can then make an ajax request to your module controller to get new options for your color dropdown.Replace the color options with the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have attributes for the products as attributes can be used as filters but you will have to make changes in the options.phtml according to the option name and the attribute name matching

Answer (score -1):

In custom option there is children field, simply include id's that you want to show for particular option. 
or you can go through the Jquery but that will be quiet inefficient.

[image: As there is children in choose cover type do make sure you have the children field and associate that children field to other field.]